# FuzzyLookupFactory is not working with Arabic words

Tags: sxa, content-search, solr

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I'm using FuzzyLookupFactory for my suggester, and this is the configuration:

```
    <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">sxaSuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">suggestion_s</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggester</str>
        <str name="maxEdits">2</str>
        <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
        <str name="nonFuzzyPrefix">0</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">sxaSuggester</str>
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">30</str>
        <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

and the configuration for "text_suggester" field :

```
<fieldType name="text_suggester" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.ArabicNormalizationFilterFactory" />
     <filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory" />
     <charfilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" " />
 </analyzer>
```

When I type for example: "الخدمات"

The results are :

أديبك

اعماق موسيقية

Comment: I fixed it, I remove the stemming :
<filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>

Comment: Please make a answer and accept

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, I removed the stemming :

```
<filter class="solr.ArabicStemFilterFactory"/>
```